# Looping through a fetch request

Tags: node.js, discord

I have a list of users in my database and I want to fetch their data from Discord's API

I am unable to view the data and when I use `resolve(users.json());` I get *TypeError: users.json is not a function*

My function:

```
async function getTopUsers(discord_id) {
// Get Token
const token = await db.query(`SELECT accesstoken FROM tokens WHERE discord_id = ${discord_id}`);
const encryptedAccessToken = token.rows[0].accesstoken;
const decrypted = decrypt(encryptedAccessToken);
const accessToken = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
// Get list top users
const topUsers = await db.query(`SELECT discord_user, discord_user_points FROM discord ORDER BY discord_user_points DESC LIMIT 10`)

return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {

        const users = [];

        // Loop through top users and fetch them from discord api
        for (let i = 0; i < topUsers.rows.length; i++) {
            const user = await fetch(`${DISCORD_API}/users/${topUsers.rows[i].discord_user}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.DISCORDTOKEN}` }
            });
            users.push(user);
        }

        resolve(users.json());
    } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you have to call `.json()` on the direct response from the `fetch()` call, not on the array itself.

You also do not need to wrap another promise around existing promises.  Here's a simplified and fixed version:

```
async function getTopUsers(discord_id) {
    // Get Token
    const token = await db.query(`SELECT accesstoken FROM tokens WHERE discord_id = ${discord_id}`);
    const encryptedAccessToken = token.rows[0].accesstoken;
    const decrypted = decrypt(encryptedAccessToken);
    const accessToken = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    // Get list top users
    const topUsers = await db.query(
        `SELECT discord_user, discord_user_points FROM discord ORDER BY discord_user_points DESC LIMIT 10`)

    const users = [];
    try {
        // Loop through top users and fetch them from discord api
        for (let i = 0; i < topUsers.rows.length; i++) {
            const resp = await fetch(`${DISCORD_API}/users/${topUsers.rows[i].discord_user}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.DISCORDTOKEN}` }
            });
            const user = await resp.json();
            users.push(user);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
    return users;

}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I am new to promise/async, your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it you create an array of responses. If you want to jsonify the user you probably need to do

`users.push(await user.json())`